# Get the user's name and email from OpenID Logged In Username

Tags: asp.net, openid

I am using OpenID with Google to login into my web page. I want to retrieve the email and user's first and last names to know who is logging in to my web page.

Comment: dude, this is a web site that people answer voluntarily.  Since it very **urgent** to you it is not urgent to the people who answers...anyway have a look at this article http://bhaidar.net/post/2011/04/04/OpenID-Single-Sign-On-ASPNET-Web-Forms.aspx

Comment: Ok U Go to ur work dnt count urgency or ....

Comment: have a look at your profile faq, no answers, no vote cast and havn't accepted any answers yet.. seems like you come here to do your work only

Comment: I am Sorry for that i am new here i dnt know how to accept answers.Canu tell me how to do this

Comment: There is an outline of a check mark to the left of each answer which you can **click**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see here for an example  about [Integrating OpenID in an ASP.NET MVC Application using DotNetOpenAuth](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2009/Sep/17/Integrating-OpenID-in-an-ASPNET-MVC-Application-using-DotNetOpenAuth)

Comment: Dear i am not using MVC i am using simple asp.net 2.0 tell me how can i use OPenID in it

Comment: visit this website http://www.dotnetopenauth.net  its asp.net library for OpenID authentication....there is sample code available how to use it in your asp.net application.....